# Cutting specific chunks from a Haskell String

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to cut chunks from a list, with a given predicate. I would have preferred to use a double character, e.g. `~/`, but have resolved to just using `$`. What I essentially want to do is this...

`A: "Hello, my $name is$ Danny and I $like$ Haskell"`

What I want to turn this into is this:

`B: "Hello, my Danny and I Haskell"`

So I want to strip everything in between the given symbol, `$`, or my first preference was `~/`, if I can figure it out. What I tried was this:

```
s1 :: String -> String
s1 xs = takeWhile (/= '$') xs

s2 :: String -> String
s2 xs = dropWhile (/= '$') xs

s3 :: String -> String
s3 xs = s3 $ s2 $ s1 xs
```

This solution seems to just bug my IDE out (possibly infinite looping).

Solution:

```
s3 :: String -> String
s3 xs
 |'$' `notElem` xs = xs
 |otherwise = takeWhile (/= '$') xs ++ (s3 $ s1 xs)

s1 :: String -> String
s1 xs = drop 1 $ dropWhile (/= '$') $ tail $ snd $ break ('$'==) xs
```

Comment: You example `A` actually generates `Hello,.my..Danny.and.I..Haskell`. I use points instead of spaces since somehow SO cuts superfluous whitespace in comments (even in code blocks).

Comment: Nice job! Note that `drop 1` is just `tail`. Also, you could probably clean up the code a little but by using pattern matching and a `where` clause. As @ChrisMartin said, `Parser`s can also be used, especially for more complicated problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your infinite loop comes from calling `s3` recursively with no base case:

```
s3 :: String -> String
s3 xs = s3 $ s2 $ s1 xs
```

Adding a base case corrects the infinite loop:

```
s3 xs
  | '$' `notElem` xs = xs
  | otherwise = ...
```

This is not the whole answer. Think about what `s1` actually does and where you use its return value:

```
s1 "hello $my name is$ ThreeFx" == "hello "
```

For further reference, see the [`break`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:break) function:

```
break :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
```

Comment: Thank you for answering (and editing my post, was trying to get that format for ages).

So, the output of s1 should be added to a new list (my guess), or to the end of what is left after s2 has been ran? I have looked at your example of s1, and obviously like mine, it drops the entire rest of the string, and just takes the content before the $, so how would I amend that to get everything after the $ passed to s2?

Comment: @DannyWilson You're welcome! To format your code as code use only four spaces, *not* prefaced with `>`.

Comment: The main problem I'm having with Haskell is learning the syntax, so with your guard, the first case passes when the parsing is complete (I'm guessing), then the otherwise is what will call the  takeWhile/dropWhile functions?

Comment: @DannyWilson Yes exactly.

Comment: So, what I'm thinking is, the result of s1 is essentially just the first part of the text. So if I then passed the original string to the dropWhile function, got it to end at the end character, joined that result to the original result and ran through s3 again recursively? 

This sounds feasible but the only way I can think of getting it working is using a different end character to the start character, any tip on how to do it with the same character? Because my dropWhile will just cut off at the first $ otherwise?

Comment: Thank you for all your help, managed to solve (in case you are interested). I will edit it into the main post!

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a nice application for parsers. A solution using [trifecta](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/trifecta):

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Functor
import Text.Trifecta

input :: String
input = "Hello, my $name is$ Danny and I $like$ Haskell"
```

---

```
cutChunk :: CharParsing f => f String
cutChunk = "" <$ (char '$' *> many (notChar '$') <* char '$')
```

`cutChunk` matches `$`, followed by 0 or more (`many`) non-`$` characters, then another `$`. Then we use `("" <$)` to make this parser's value always be the empty string, thus discarding all the characters that this parser matches.

---

```
includeChunk :: CharParsing f => f String
includeChunk = some (notChar '$')
```

`includeChunk` matches the text that we want to include in the result, which is anything that's not the `$` character. It's important that we use `some` (matching one or more characters) and not `many` (matching zero or more characters) because we're going to include this parser within another `many` expression next; if this parser matched on the empty string, then that could loop infinitely.

---

```
chunks :: CharParsing f => f String
chunks = fold <$> many (cutChunk <|> includeChunk)
```

`chunks` is the parser for everything. Read `<|>` as "or", as in "parse either a `cutChunk` or an `includeChunk`". `many (cutChunk <|> includeChunk)` is a parser that produces a list of chunks e.g. `Success ["Hello, my ",""," Danny and I ",""," Haskell"]`, so we `fold` the output to concatenate those chunks together into a single string.

---

```
result :: Result String
result = parseString chunks mempty input
```

The result:

```
Success "Hello, my  Danny and I  Haskell"
```

Comment: Thank you for the added solution! The actual libraries I'm working on are parsers, and I really wanted to do it from the bottom up, bringing in more advanced parsing (like your example) later on. Thank you for your solution though! Was an interesting read, and will no doubt help me later in my project!

Comment: This is an elegant approach. Maybe adding some comments could also make it more accessible to who never used trifecta. Most of it is self-documenting, to a trained eye, but I had to pause to guess e.g. why `"" <$` and why `fold <$>`.

Comment: Some comments would be helpful! (It would help when I come to more advanced parsing)

Comment: @ChrisMartin That edit helps a lot! Thank you! Would you consider this solution, or my edit to the original post, more efficient?

Comment: I have no idea :)

Answer (score 2):

I think your logic is wrong, perhaps easier to write it in an elementary way

```
Prelude> let pr xs = go xs True
Prelude|           where go [] _ = []
Prelude|                 go (x:xs) f | x=='$' = go xs (not f)
Prelude|                             | f = x : go xs f
Prelude|                             | otherwise = go xs f
Prelude|

Prelude> pr "Hello, my $name is$ Danny and I $like$ Haskell"
"Hello, my  Danny and I  Haskell"
```

**Explanation**  The flag `f` keeps track of the state (either pass mode or not).  If the current char is a token skip and switch state.

Comment: This is interesting, certainly simpler than my approach. I don't suppose you could explain it a little more so I can use similar logic in the future? The go and single colon part in particular?